# Making an internal microphone waterproof

Tags: audio, waterproof

I am incredibly new to audio and was wondering if you guys could help me out.

I am trying to find a way of keeping an enclosure watertight whilst picking up audio using a digital surface mount microphone.

Can I use some sort of membrane over a hole in the enclosure to keep the water out but not loose too much sound quality? If so do you have suggestions on a good material?

Unfortunately this is all I have come up with so far and I have not been able to find any small (roughly 30mm^2 or less) digital microphones that are waterproof.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Genuinely, a condom might be able to help you here. I have read several times of people fitting them completely over their mics to combat wet conditions. Perhaps in the case of an enclosure, you could still utilise the material even if you can't fit it over. I'm sure it will affect the sound slightly but that is probably unavoidable and it's really about weighing up the compromise.

There are some great waterproof mics on the market, for instance, DPA makes "heavy duty" versions of some of their compact mics which can be fully submerged, but these are quite expensive (and not digital).

Also, if you are actually recording underwater, you might want to look into getting a hydrophone.

Hope that helps!